# UserControl ClientRectangle is smaller than it says

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to make my UserControl with custom borders (I changed default border style to "none" in properties - I created control and I am invoking Graphics.DrawRectangle(...,ClientRectangle). And what I see is only the top and left borders of my painted rectangle - it seems that real size of the area where I can draw is different than ClientRectangle... How to change it / get the right ClientRectangle size?

Comment: Yes of course, you want to draw on the *inside* of the rectangle.  You must make it one pixel smaller.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#". That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

ClientRectangle returns the rectangle in **exclusive coordinates** so you need to subtract 1 from the bottom and right hand sides. This will work regardless of how many units per pixel there are in the current graphics mode, someone correct me if I am wrong.