# Properly Sizing Custom-Drawn Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, gdi+

I'm attempting to make a custom control that properly draws itself to fill its current size. I was under the assumption that I should use the [ClientRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) property for sizing, but the right and bottom of the client rectangle seem to be getting clipped.

Filling the draw event handler with

```
Rectangle smaller = new Rectangle(5, 5, ClientRectangle.Width - 10, ClientRectangle.Height - 10);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, smaller);  
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, ClientRectangle);
```

yields this:

[image: ClientRecangle is clipped]

What should I be using to get the drawable area of the control?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8377709/577417

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pixel behaviour of FillRectangle and DrawRectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147569/pixel-behaviour-of-fillrectangle-and-drawrectangle)

Comment: @Benjamin The answer from the possible duplicate seems _almost_ correct. It seems that you need to subtract 2, not 1, from the bottom and right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use:

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, this.ClientRectangle, _
                        Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

where `Graphics g = e.Graphics;`.

Or draw it as you did but subtracting 1 from width and height (1 because width and height are inclusive but draw rectangle needs the size exclusive the last pixel - internally it calculates `x + w/y + h` which then ends up at the position for the *next* pixel after the last, hence we need to subtract one to get the position for the *last* pixel).

```
rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;
r.Width -= 1;
r.Height -= 1;

g.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, r);
```

And of course this from within the `OnPaint` event handler.

Comment: It seems that you need to subtract 2, not 1, from the bottom and right. Thanks!